# Check files after git push, or; best practices for github after push tests

Tags: testing, github

Sometimes our developers push -simple to find- mistakes to our repos, like a missing ";" a "console.log" that is not suppose to be in the main branch, or an invalid json file. With Github you can add webhooks when there is a push event, and with that I can create scripts (on our servers) that download the modified/added file and based on the extension lunch different types of tests (mainly in nodejs). But this is not an easy task and I feel that I'm reinventing the wheel.

I know you can use pre-push script on the developer machines or set the code IDE to prevent commits when there are mistakes, but I prefer a centralized solution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I hope you use branches in git. Please do if you haven't so far.
Then if you have branches you can do pull requests. Good step to perform branch validation. Now you should really invest some time in CI tool (e.g. Jenkins). 
You can create different pipelines there with steps like build, tests, deploy to qa, deploy to prod and many more. The common case is to use it for the artifact from master branch. But it is also quite easy to integrate these tool and run pipeline with different tests when pull requests is created. It will give you some nice indication before manual code review. 
So to sum up, 
1) code on branch -> 
2) pull request created -> 
3) pull request triggers pipline with tests on CI tool -> 
4) success/fail message on pull request page -> 
5) merge if code reivew performed and everything is ok.